# UnityWebRequest not sending POST data

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post

When Unity sends the POST request it doesn't pass the POST data, so the server returns an error (it gets the server response). I've seen that several people had a similar issue and it got fixed by adding `www.chunkedTransfer = false;`, however, that doesn't work for me.

I've also seen that some people use `WWWForm` instead of `IMultipartFormSection`, but I haven't tried it because it is deprecated.

I'm using PHP, but I've also tried it with Perl and it didn't work either. When I manually send a POST request everything works normally, so it seems the issue is in Unity. I'm new to Unity, so any help would be appreciated. I'm using the current latest version, 2018.2.18f1 Personal.

My code is pretty much the same as the [official Unity documentation for sending POST request](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html), but apparently it doesn't work. Here is my code:

C#:

```
public void Click() {
    StartCoroutine(PostRequest("http://127.0.0.1/test.php", "help"));
}

IEnumerator PostRequest(string url, string data) {
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("data=" + data));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo "Server received: " . $_POST["data"]; ?>
```

Comment: In your PHP, you could dump out from the `php://input` stream to see what the request body looks like.

Comment: Never worked with unity, but according to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection-ctor.html I guess it should be MultipartFormDataSection("data", data)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Wow, that actually fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Christoph Lütjen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085502/christoph-l%C3%BCtjen) pointed out that according to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection-ctor.html) it should be `new MultipartFormDataSection("data", data)`, despite the [official documentation example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) using `new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar")`.

Changing it to `new MultipartFormDataSection("data", data)` fixed the issue.